# Passing '' (empty) for an INT type column in INSERT query in mysql working for some configuration but not working for other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table "test_tab" with three columns -

a (INT) (primary key) (auto increment)

b (INT) (NOT NULL)

c (INT) (NOT NULL)

Column 'b' and 'c' do not have any default value.

When I use below INSERT queries, it works for some phpMyAdmin, PHP and MySQL configuration but for other configuration it's not working and showing below error in phpMyAdmin -

Query 1:

**INSERT INTO `test_db`.`test_table` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES ('', '2', '')**

Error -

**1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'a' at row 1**

Query 2:

**INSERT INTO `test_db`.`test_table` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '')**

Error -

**1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'c' at row 1**

**Here is the configuration in which query is working -**
[image]

**And here is the configuration in which query is not working -**
[image]

Comment: I have no idea about PhpMyAdmin but that behaviour is controlled by [SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: They probably have a different SQL mode config.

Comment: it's better to pass NULL to int column, not ''.

Comment: @Álvaro González and @ Mark Rotteveel : You may be right. What do you think can be the proper SQL mode setting to resolve above issue?

Comment: The `STRICT_...` ones.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research on SQL Modes suggested above, I got the answer-

Step 1 : First I checked the currently active SQL modes using below query -

**SELECT @@sql_mode**

Step 2 : Removed all active SQL modes using below query -

**SET GLOBAL sql_mode =''**

Then it worked fine for me.

**Important Note :**
This will work till the time MySQL is not restarted. If you restart MySQL then you will have to run below query again -

SET GLOBAL sql_mode =''